# Script that converts a string to a date, compares this date to today's date and counts this date if it is earlier

Tags: string, date, count, twig

I work for a company that makes web portals for libraries.

Today, I work mainly with subscriber data.

Here is some of subscriber data:

```
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(19) "8235798454376842909"
  ["username"]=>
  string(12) "Test xxxx"
  ["login"]=>
  string(11) "xxxx"
  ["role"]=>
  string(5) "guest"
  ["account"]=>
  string(4) "opac"
  ["details"]=>
  array(27) {
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(7) "xxxx"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["subscriptions"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(12) {
        ["subscription"]=>
        array(17) {
          ["ruleSetsLateLoan"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            array(3) {
              ["id"]=>
              string(19) "6661733132890635183"
              ["name"]=>
              string(16) "Tous docs retard"
              ["deleted"]=>
              bool(false)
            }
          }
        }
        ["endDate"]=>
        string(10) "06-05-2022"
        ["startDate"]=>
        string(10) "06-05-2021"
      }
    }
    ["loans"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(17) {
        ["objectType"]=>
        string(9) "User\Loan"
        ["id"]=>
        string(19) "7348367352886005629"
        ["startDate"]=>
        string(10) "20-10-2021"

        ["endDate"]=>
        string(10) "10-11-2021"

        ["returnDate"]=>
        NULL
        ["returnLibrary"]=>
        string(22) "Bibliothèque Brassens"
        ["extendable"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["nonExtendabilityReason"]=>
        NULL
        ["bibrecordId"]=>
        string(18) "224787138527266506"
        ["bibrecordTitle"]=>
        string(33) "La jeune fille et la nuit : roman"
        ["bibrecordResponsibles"]=>
        string(15) "Guillaume Musso"
        ["bibrecordEditor"]=>
        string(13) "Calmann-Lévy"
        ["bibrecordPublishedDate"]=>
        NULL
        ["isElectronical"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["bibrecordCode"]=>
        string(13) "9782702163634"
        ["bibrecordType"]=>
        string(5) "Texte"
        ["late"]=>
        bool(true)
      }
    }
    ["subenddate"]=>
    string(10) "06-05-2022"
  }
}
```

From these, I would like:

1. Know if there are overdue loans
2. If yes, how much?

As you can see from the loans data:

- startDate
- **endDate** (*it is especially this one that interests me*)

are strings

I call on your expertise because I would like to set up a script with Twig variables which:

- convert the ***loan*** > ***endDate*** string into a date
- compare this date to today's date
- if the ***endDate*** is prior to today's date, count it (because it means that the subscriber has an overdue loan)
- (*finally*) retrieve this number, this result

I appeal to you because my knowledge is limited to HTML/CSS and 2-3 Twig functions.

By searching on the Internet, I should be able to do the first 2 actions (convert the string of characters from loan > endDate to a date and compare this date to the current date), but since each action takes the result of the previous one... I don't know how to do

Can you help me please ?

In advance, thank you for your help

Have a nice day

Comment: This is not something you should be doing inside twig

Comment: However, if I want to retrieve, for example, the user's name, I indicate the following Twig variable:
`<div>Hello, my username is {{ session_user.username }}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the data relating to the subscriber's loans:

```
["loans"]=>
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(17) {
    ["objectType"]=>
    string(9) "User\Loan"
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "1030181343798038358"
    ["startDate"]=>
    string(10) "24-08-2022"
    ["endDate"]=>
    string(10) "26-08-2022"
    ["returnDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["returnLibrary"]=>
    string(22) "Bibliothèque Cendrars"
    ["extendable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["nonExtendabilityReason"]=>
    NULL
    ["bibrecordId"]=>
    string(19) "8412379444127231486"
    ["bibrecordTitle"]=>
    string(22) "Monika. ; Jeux d'été"
    ["bibrecordResponsibles"]=>
    string(14) "Ingmar Bergman"
    ["bibrecordEditor"]=>
    string(7) "Opening"
    ["bibrecordPublishedDate"]=>
    string(4) "2001"
    ["isElectronical"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["bibrecordCode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["bibrecordType"]=>
    string(23) "Ressource électronique"
    ["late"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(17) {
    ["objectType"]=>
    string(9) "User\Loan"
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "1671289858474018264"
    ["startDate"]=>
    string(10) "29-06-2021"
    ["endDate"]=>
    string(10) "20-07-2021"
    ["returnDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["returnLibrary"]=>
    string(22) "Bibliothèque Cendrars"
    ["extendable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["nonExtendabilityReason"]=>
    NULL
    ["bibrecordId"]=>
    string(19) "9064740467286336344"
    ["bibrecordTitle"]=>
    string(22) "Le château des pianos"
    ["bibrecordResponsibles"]=>
    string(31) "Pierre Créac'h, textes & comp."
    ["bibrecordEditor"]=>
    string(13) "Ed. Sarbacane"
    ["bibrecordPublishedDate"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["isElectronical"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["bibrecordCode"]=>
    string(13) "9782848657066"
    ["bibrecordType"]=>
    string(5) "Texte"
    ["late"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(17) {
    ["objectType"]=>
    string(9) "User\Loan"
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "2671623005489329067"
    ["startDate"]=>
    string(10) "29-06-2021"
    ["endDate"]=>
    string(10) "28-07-2023"
    ["returnDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["returnLibrary"]=>
    string(20) "Médiathèque Aragon"
    ["extendable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["nonExtendabilityReason"]=>
    NULL
    ["bibrecordId"]=>
    string(19) "5404768465078117954"
    ["bibrecordTitle"]=>
    string(37) "Château l'attente : Addendum (2 / 2)"
    ["bibrecordResponsibles"]=>
    string(12) "Linda Medley"
    ["bibrecordEditor"]=>
    string(8) "Delcourt"
    ["bibrecordPublishedDate"]=>
    string(4) "2013"
    ["isElectronical"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["bibrecordCode"]=>
    string(13) "9782756039985"
    ["bibrecordType"]=>
    string(5) "Texte"
    ["late"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(17) {
    ["objectType"]=>
    string(9) "User\Loan"
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "6187422550922662455"
    ["startDate"]=>
    string(10) "24-08-2022"
    ["endDate"]=>
    string(10) "26-08-2022"
    ["returnDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["returnLibrary"]=>
    string(22) "Bibliothèque Cendrars"
    ["extendable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["nonExtendabilityReason"]=>
    NULL
    ["bibrecordId"]=>
    string(19) "2571403561722263349"
    ["bibrecordTitle"]=>
    string(39) "Une Étude en rouge -- livre numérique"
    ["bibrecordResponsibles"]=>
    string(20) " Doyle, Arthur Conan"
    ["bibrecordEditor"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["bibrecordPublishedDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["isElectronical"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["bibrecordCode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["bibrecordType"]=>
    string(23) "Ressource électronique"
    ["late"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

If you look at ["late"], there is a boolean test on each document to know if it is late or not.

How to count the number of true booleans in an array? Knowing that in the example above, the answer is 3 (out of 4 loans)